# What is this syntax: []._

Tags: javascript

I seen `[]._` in someones code. What is this and what is it used for?

```
notes_array = ["C", 1046.50]
reduced=[], notes_array.reduce((a,b,i,c,r,l=["name","frequency"])=>( r=a||{},r[l[i%2]]=isNaN(b)?b.trim():b,a?(reduced.push(r),[]._):r ),false);
```

[Copied from here](http://codepen.io/JamesTheHacker/pen/ZOxQwa?editors=1111)

The only thing I can think of is it's a short hand for undefined? That's a guess though.

Comment: That seems like a good guess.

Comment: The code looks like minified, can you add original code

Comment: @Tushar no. That's the only code I have. It was pasted by a colleague on Slack.

Comment: `[]` is an empty array and `_` refers to a property of it. By default the property should not be defined. There's a javasript library called underscore.js, could it be involved?

Comment: No because no library could override that. With underscore, the `_` is an object. This is the other way around, it's accessing a property `_` on an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That evaluates to `undefined` (as it is trying to access a property of an empty array), and it uses less characters than the word `undefined`. It is used in minified code and also in code golf to behave the same as `undefined` would, but only using 4 characters instead of 9.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it is `undefined`. It just changed the last statement to:

```
console.log([]._)
```

and it printed `undefined`